# Jenkins & Newman: HTMLEXTRA report gets published on project level using Jenkins html publisher only for successful Jenkins builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, postman, newman

I have set up a `Jenkins` multibranch-pipeline executing `Postman` tests using `Newman`. My used reporters are `-r cli,htmlextra,junit,junitfull`.

The `HTMLEXTRA` report does get published using the `Jenkins htmlpublisher` on the project level, however, only for successful Jenkins builds. In other words, only when all API tests pass, the `HTMLEXTRA` report is accessible directly from the project menu as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image: project level menu]

For failing builds, the `HTMLEXTRA` reports do get created though and I can open them in the menu for each single Jenkins run, but not on the overall project level. There only the latest successful build report is linked.

My `POSTACTIONS` Jenkins stage looks like this:

```
post {
        always {
            archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'build/report.html', fingerprint: true

             publishHTML (target: [ //DOCUMENTATION can be found here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher/
                  allowMissing: false, //If checked, will allow report to be missing and build will not fail on missing report.
                  alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true, //If this control and "Keep past HTML reports" are checked, publish the link on project level even if build failed.
                  keepAll: true, //If checked, archive reports for all successful builds, otherwise only the most recent.
                  reportDir: 'build', //The path to the HTML report directory relative to the workspace.
                  reportFiles: 'report.html', //The file(s) to provide links inside the report directory.
                  reportName: 'Newman Test Report'
              ])

              junit "build/report-full.xml"
        }
    }
```

My understanding was that if `alwaysLinkToLastBuild` and `keepAll` are both `true`, the link to the latest `HTMLEXTRA` report gets published on project level even for failing builds. See here the official documentation https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher.

Can you help me, please, with publishing `HTMLEXTRA` reports on the project level even for failed Jenkins builds? Thanks a lot!